# How to change gravity source in sprite Kit scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, 2d

I want all my SKNodes that are being affected from gravity to go to the horizontal Line on my SKScene view and not to the bottom. Something like a line that is a gravity pole. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [SKFieldNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skfieldnode) ?

It has various simulations regarding physics; for example, it can create the

```
class func radialGravityField() -> SKFieldNode
```

Which does the following:

> Creates a field node that accelerates physics bodies toward the field node.

**Edit:**

Here is an example done in Playground of how an SKFieldNode works with an SKShapeNode

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
      let sampleNodeRadius: CGFloat = 15
      let gravityNode = SKFieldNode.radialGravityField()
      let sampleNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: sampleNodeRadius)

      sampleNode.fillColor = .red
      sampleNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: sampleNodeRadius)

      gravityNode.minimumRadius = 1000
      gravityNode.strength = 50

      addChild(gravityNode)
      addChild(sampleNode)

      physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

      sampleNode.position = CGPoint(x: -100, y: -100)

      gravityNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
   }
```